# Wrong version of Symfony got installed

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I'm trying to check out(try) symfony 4, but when I try to install it via composer, the version 3.4.5 is getting installed?

I have used the same commands given in the docs

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony_4_practice
Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.5)
- Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.5): Downloading (100%)
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Your environment doesn't meet the minimum requirements for install Symfony 4, composer installs the latest version your environment can support which is Symfony 3. If you try this: **composer create-project symfony/skeleton:4** your going to have an error message with details of what you need to change in your local environment to meet the Symfony 4 requirements

Answer (score 3):

You must have php < 7.1, hence the Symfony 3.4

Upgrade to PHP 7.1 or more and you'll be all set.

---

Edit: as precised per [bouchon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874292/bouchon), the PHP requirement can be found on [the packagist package page](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton).

It is also possible to see that directly in the package [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton/blob/4.0/composer.json#L7).

Comment: my php version in 7.1.2

Comment: @vikasetagi : Symfony requires at least PHP 7.1.3
Source : [https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:4.0 symfony_4_practice
```

this command force the version

Comment: I go this error "  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package symfony/skeleton with version 4.0 in a version installable using your PHP version 7.1.2."

Comment: If you look into composer.json from symfony/skeleton you can see it need at least the 7.1.3 version

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
composer self-update
composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony_4_practice
```

I think you need to update composer only

Comment: I tried the the same flow, it installed v3.4.5 after that

Comment: This will continue to install the version compatible with @vikasetagi environment which is Symfony 3